# S3FS Mount does not seem to work: Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: debian, s3fs

So I've just a brand new VPS which I'll be using for nextcloud. I followed [this](https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001744651-How-do-I-use-S3FS-with-Wasabi-) guide.
I did (on a brand new machine):

1. Apt install s3fs
2. Create a /etc/passwd-s3fs file with key:secret key
3. Chmoded it 600
4. Ran s3fs nameofmywasabibucket /mnt/wasabi -o passwd_file=/etc/passwd-s3fs -o url=https://s3.wasabisys.com
   I got the typical linux "Mhm" (nothing logged), meaning nothing went wrong right?
5. Created a hello.txt inside of /mnt/wasabi but it doesn't seem to be any different than any other directory... Nothing comes up in files on my wasabi bucket

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: For european Servers, you have to use s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com instead of s3.wasabisys.com PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score 3):

Solved it on my own, the problem was that if you are not using the default server location, try looking at this page: https://wasabi-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015106031-What-are-the-service-URLs-for-Wasabi-s-different-regions-

replace the url with your server's location

Fixed my problem!